# Chrome 33.0.1750.117 m, background icon extension is orange

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, icons, browser-action

I post here to see if you have an idea of ​​what may be this bug, met last night making changes to my Chrome extension. Since the background of the icon-extension is orange and does not change :

http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/388737bug.png

*The first icon is the local extension, the second from Chrome Web Store*

Here are the views of the icon, when enabled and when it is not. This bug (?) is seen only on Google Chrome, not Chromium or Canary.

```
Link extension activated : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/791653icon19.png

Link extension disabled : http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/751957icon19deactivate.png
```

I'm working on Windows 7, but I have not yet tried to uninstall Chrome to see if that solved the problem.

Manifest.json :

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "YouTube Dark Theme : Black and Red",
    "short_name": "Black & Red",
    "description": "Youtube theme : Specially for night or prevent the flash effect overnight.",
    "version": "1.29",
    "permissions": [
        "http://www.youtube.com/"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.youtube.com/*", "https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["youtube_theme_b_r.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://apis.google.com/*/widget/render/comments*", "*://plus.googleapis.com/*/widget/render/comments*"],
      "js": ["youtube_theme_b_r_comments.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html",
        "persistent": false
    },
      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "images/icon_19.png",
        "default_title": "Youtube Dark Theme : Black and Red"
    },
    "icons": {
        "19": "images/icon_19.png",
        "48": "images/icon_48.png",
        "96": "images/icon_96.png"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "youtube_dark_theme_min.css",
        "youtube_dark_theme_comments_min.css"
    ]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Post your manifest.json.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I edit my first post with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome 33 is when Chromium is tightening security and only allowing extensions from the webstore (or as a developer or with enterprise policy.)

http://www.chromium.org/developers/extensions-deployment-faq

I couldn't find anything about the background being orange, but it's happening on my unpacked extension too (but not on my published one.)

So it just makes it more obvious that the extension wasn't from the webstore (safer for regular users, and lets developers differentiate from their published extensions.)

Comment: Thank you, I also think the background change takes place only on the extensions that are not from the Chrome Web Store, so as to differentiate and / or warn the user.

Comment: @TyrionGraphiste its unpacked verses packed. That is it. If you pack up an local unpacked extension, and then install the extension 'still locally' it will not be orange. I like it as it allows me to easily see the difference between my dev and released extension without having to temporarily changing the dev versions icon for easy recognition.